# Whatever happened to the 50-point bounties?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

Are they no longer allowed? Is this a local policy or a stackwide one?

Comment: Was it on a question you had already answered? If so, then no, 50 rep bounties aren't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it with old unanswered questions of mine both on this stack, and on SO, and both seemed to work.